# Jetpack Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout Initial Height

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I’m looking to create a ModalBottomSheetLayout in Jetpack Compose that has an initial height but can still be dragged up to reveal more content (assuming there is more content to show).

So for example if I want the bottom sheet to start at 25% of the screen height when initially shown, it should expand that far at first then if the user drags up it will expand more. Is there a way I can do this easily? I have tried a few different ways but nothing seems to work properly